# How to grant permission for localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have given this working code on terminal to grant access to root on ubuntu but the grant command is not found.

```
~/frappe-bench$ GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

> GRANT: command not found

Comment: I assume you're supposed to do this for a database? Because the `GRANT` command you use, and the way you use it, is typically used for SQL databases

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Your not really asking a correct question in my opinion, but here's what you need I guess. This gives all permissions to your user on the specific database.

Make sure you install mysql client first and then login to the database

```
mysql -h localhost -u <youruser> -p
```

-Enter your password after running command above